# Data structure for storing structures containing multiple strings in C

Tags: c, data-structures, markov-chains

What kind of data structure should I use to store structures containing arrays of strings in C ?

Certain structures need to be easily accessible and time of the look-up should be possibly short.
I've been considering hash table but it turned out to be not so efficient after all.

I need to store n-grams of words read from a text file , n=1,2,... .

For instance in 3-gram : " I need help " 
 {"I" , "need"} is a prefix and "help" is a suffix.

```
struct data {
      char **prefix;
      char **suffix;
      int *occurrence;
};
```

Prefix and possible suffixes with number of occurrence after that prefix should be stored in those structures, thus I need a very easy access.

Then I would have to draw an initial prefix and randomly pick suffix with certain probability(according to the number of occurrence) then look-up newly got prefix and so on until I get  text of proper length.

This is gonna be text generator based on Markov-chains.

Comment: First: replace the strings by numbers (token-nuber := the index into your dictionary) Second: you could structure the N-grams as a tree (you might need a second tree for the reversed string)

Comment: @wildplasser could you give me a hint how to replace strings of unknown length by numbers ?

Comment: If they are not already there: put them in a dictionary structure (most often a hashtable). Otherwise: refer to the existing dirtionary entry.